# How to change which field is used as _id without annotations in Spring data MongoDB

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

I have some classes which are being generated from a WSDL using the CXF wsdl2java tool.
I would like to store instances of these classes in a MongoDB database, using Spring data MongoDB.
The default mapping is acceptable for this, except for one thing:
I would like to change which field is used as _id.

Normally this is done with a annotation like @Id.
But because these classes are generated, I would like to do this without an annotation.
Is there a (correct?) way to do this?

So my generated class is:

```
class Simple {
    String businessId;
    String otherfield1;
    .
    String otherfield999;
}
```

And I would like Spring data MongoDB to use 'businessId' as the '_id' field in MongoDB, without changing the 'Simple' class by adding an annotation.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's currently not supported. The property either needs to be `id`, `_id` or annotated with `@Id`.